# How can I get a dynamically assigned widget to display HTML in Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to get my custom widget to display without the HTML being escaped by Django. Here's my widget:

```
class MyInput(Widget):

  def __init__(self, obj, attrs=None):

    super(MyInput, self).__init__(attrs)

  def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):

    return mark_safe(u'<img src="{url}">').format(url=self.url)
```

It gets instantiated via a form factory:

```
def MyFormFactory():
  class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

      super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      desired_fields = ['field1', 'field2',]
      for f in desired_fields:
        self.fields[f].widget = MyInput(self.instance)

  return MyForm
```

This gets called in my Django Admin class:

```
class MyAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyFormFactory()
```

Everything 'works' except for the fact that my widget has its HTML escaped. This does not happen if I use the widget via direct form instantiation (using a regular form class and form field widget assignment), but I need to be able to set it up via the factory like this. How can I force Django to allow the HTML? allow_tags doesn't seem to apply in this case, and I've already used mark_safe. What am I still missing?

Comment: Take a look how [Django built-in widget implement `render()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py). Try use `format_html()` too. Does it help?

Comment: @alecxe I have read that. format_html() makes no difference, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
return mark_safe(u'<img src="{url}">').format(url=self.url)
```

to

```
return mark_safe(u'<img src="{url}">'.format(url=self.url))
```

The first line returns a string, the latter returns a `SafeBytes` instance, and Django treats them differently.

Comment: Nailed it. That was it.